# How to get default Pages folder programmatically in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, c-sharp

Using C# in Sharepoint 2013 I can reach `Pages` folder using `web.Folders["Pages"]` or `web.GetFolder("Pages")`

Some of our `SPWeb`s are in Turkish language. Whole interface is in Turkish including all default folders.

Problem is `Pages` becomes `Sayfalar` in Turkish. Other folder names also different but their internal names are in English so it's not a big deal but `Pages` internal name is also in Turkish `Sayfalar`.

This could be a problem in other languages too. `Pages` may become something else.

So is there a way to get default `Pages` folder programmatically in any language without using `if..then..else`

Comment: Why can't you simply get the library by url? Is url different in Turkish? Proposed solution in not effective due to iteration over all lists.

Comment: @Kai yes url in Turkish site is `http://domain/sites/xyz/tr/Sayfalar/Forms/AllItems.aspx` while in English it is `http://domain/sites/xyz/en/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx` and it might be different in other languages. I want to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(http://url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
        {
            if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
            {

                SPDocumentLibrary docLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)list;
                if (docLibrary.BaseTemplate == (SPListTemplateType)850)

                    Console.WriteLine("Pages Library")

            }
        }
    }
}
```